# How to store and access API keys and passwords with Gatsby?

Tags: security, passwords, gatsby

I am working on a Gatsby app that implements some 3rd party APIs, all requiring personal credentials. Later on I'm planning to also add a DB, so that will require credentials as well. 
Since all my code is committed to GitHub, I'm looking for a way to store and access these in a secure way.

While I haven't deployed my app yet, the solution should apply to both local development as well as production.

I'd like to mention that I've never (had the chance to) worked with similar problems in that past, thus I don't even know where to look or what I'm supposed to look for to solve this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's important to distinguish between two types of secrets in Gatsby: build-time and runtime.

- **Build-time secrets** are used in the [Gatsby build process](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/conceptual/overview-of-the-gatsby-build-process/), for example when sourcing data from a CMS (you need to use secrets to pull data from your CMS).
- **Runtime secrets** are used client-side when you fetch data from an API dynamically, for example when rendering a Mapbox map (you need to pass your API secret to Mapbox on the client).

### Build-time secrets

You can store build-time secrets as **environment variables** ([Gatsby docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/environment-variables/)).

In a nutshell, you'll create a `.env.development` file with your dev environment variables, and a `.env.production` file for your prod environment.

Then, at the beginning of your `gatsby-config.js`, you'll add this: (no need to install `dotenv`, it's already a Gatsby dependency)

```js
require("dotenv").config({
  path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
})
```

Also make sure that your `.env` files are in your `.gitignore` to avoid committing them to source control:

```
# ignore env variables files
.env*
```

As a last step, you'll need to manually add the variables to every service you're using that needs to build your site. Typically this is going to be your host ([Netlify](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/environment-variables/) for example), and your CI ([GitHub Actions](https://help.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/creating-and-storing-encrypted-secrets) for example).

### Runtime secrets

The strength of Gatsby is fetching data at build time and generating static content. If you can pull your content at build time using a Gatsby source plugin, you should favor this over fetching content at runtime. (See the Gatsby docs on [Build-time vs Runtime Data Fetching](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/data-fetching/) for more details.)

However, in some cases, you can't fetch data at build time, for example when fetching dynamic content or rendering a Mapbox map.

In this case, saving your secrets as environment variables won't be enough, because the secrets will still be exposed in network calls.

You have several alternative options, for example:

- Proxy the API calls through a backend-for-frontend, like an Express.js server, and add the secrets to your Express server
- Use serverless functions to proxy the call without having to host a server, for example with [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2021/02/18/netlify-functions-for-an-unrivaled-serverless-workflow/) or AWS Lambda

Runtime secrets in Gatsby are obviously more complex to deal with than build-time secrets. If your application relies heavily on runtime data fetching, you could also think about replacing Gatsby with [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/), which nicely supports runtime secrets through [API routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction) (essentially serverless functions bundled in the framework).

---

*Thanks to [HaberdashPI](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1354319/haberdashpi) and [JakobAttk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12287940/jakobattk) for their feedback that improved this answer!*

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: after reading a bit about what you suggested I came across some posts saying that this is a terrible way to store private keys and passwords because of the security implications. If these values are available on the client-side, can't these be accessed by virtually anyone? Does't this problem require a server-side solution?

Comment: As far as I know, the variables won't be accessible client-side unless you prefix them with `GATSBY_` (see [the docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/environment-variables/#client-side-javascript)). Can you share a source for your security concerns?

Comment: Exactly the first paragraph from the docs you linked. I don't see any difference between Project Environment Variables and OS Env Vars. The docs says both will be available in browser JavaScript.

Comment: Env vars will be used at build time by Gatsby, they won't end up in client-side JavaScript (cf [Security in Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/security-in-gatsby/#key-security)). If you need to use secrets on the client, in a fetch request for example, your payloads will be exposed just like in any frontend app, so the client will probably first request a key to authenticate calls, all client-side

Comment: Gonna have to agree with @JakobAttk on this one. This approach is a *bad* idea. There is a pretty thorough discussion of these issues on the [gatsby blog](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/blog/2019-04-06-security-for-modern-web-frameworks/)

Comment: I think that the misunderstanding here comes from the difference between build-time vs. runtime secrets. If you use the secrets during at build time (ex. you're fetching data from your DB) you're safe with environment variables. If you're calling an API with a secret at runtime (ex. you're rendering a Mapbox map), your secrets will be exposed. In this case I recommend proxying the requests through a BFF or using serverless functions. Am I missing something @HaberdashPI? If not I'll edit the answer to make this clearer for everyone :)

Comment: Agreed, I think the issue is whether the secret is available at build-time only or not. Perhaps I've misunderstood: it was not clear to me, from either the original question or the answer that the need was at build time only ("implement some 3rd party APIs..."). I think it would help to clarify that your answer is for a build-time query.

Comment: Will do, thanks a lot for your feedback @HaberdashPI! I'll also point out a few ways to handle runtime secrets

Comment: @HaberdashPI edited, let me know what you think! Feel free to suggest edits as well :)

Answer (score 2):

JakobAttk is right... if you don't use a Server or serverless Functions to provide your fetched data to the clients, everybody (with a few dev-console knowledge) is able to see the API-Keys.
It's easy like 1,2,3... you only need to open you network-tab in DEV-Tools and look for xhr connections. Figure out the fetch from the API and check the values of the headers which was send by  the request.

ENV variables are fine if you don't want to (and you never should do!!!) put your sensitive Data in git-repositories, but they are not fully hidden on runtime.

At least, the last mile to the api-service keeps the credentials for it, so never use unsecure client connections for sensitive API keys. If your API-Service has additional Security-Layer (e.g check referer IP) it might be ok.

Answer (score 1):

I personally do not love the idea of storing secrets in `.env` files, so I typically reach for something like AWS Secrets Manager these days.  You can easily set up secrets storage and fetch secret keys with the AWS SDK.  Of course this all assumes you're using AWS at some point, but I like to do it this way because I can control what roles have access to my keys -- so if you're setting up a build pipeline, this might be a good way to do it.  At build time, I might do something like this

```js
import AWS from "aws-sdk";
const region = "us-east-1";

const creds = new AWS.SharedIniFileCredentials({ profile: "some-profile-name" });
AWS.config.credentials = creds;

export class SecretsManagerService {
  private static _client: AWS.SecretsManager;

  static get client(): AWS.SecretsManager {
    if (!SecretsManagerService._client) {
      SecretsManagerService._client = new AWS.SecretsManager({
        region,
      });
    }
    return SecretsManagerService._client;
  }

  static async getSecretValue(secretId: string): Promise<string> {
    try {
      const secret = await SecretsManagerService.client
        .getSecretValue({ SecretId: secretId })
        .promise();
      return secret.SecretString!;
    } catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
  }
}
```

And, that's all well and good except you'll need to use the secrets in Gatsby, so I do something like this (let's assume that I'm using Contentful as my CMS)

```js
import { SecretsManagerService } from "./aws-secrets.service";
import { execSync } from 'child_process';

(async () => {
    const { CONTENTFUL_ENV } = process.env;
    const secretPath = CONTENTFUL_ENV === 'qa' ? 'qa-secret-path' : 'prod-secret-path';
    const values = await SecretsManagerService.getSecretValue(secretPath);
    const parsed = JSON.parse(values);
    process.env.CONTENTFUL_KEY = parsed.contentfulSecretKey;
    const command = CONTENTFUL_ENV === 'qa' ? 'gatsby develop' : 'gatsby build';
    execSync(command, { stdio: 'inherit'});
})();
```

This way I can inherit my environment variables in my Gatsby config like this (again assuming I'm using Contentful as the CMS).

```js
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-source-contentful",
      options: {
        accessToken: process.env.CONTENTFUL_KEY,
        environment: process.env.CONTENTFUL_ENV,
        spaceId: "my-space-id",
      },
    },
```

And modify your package.json scripts to be like this

```json
  "scripts": {
    "develop": "CONTENTFUL_ENV=qa ts-node ./tools/index.ts",
    "start": "gatsby develop",
    "build": "CONTENTFUL_ENV=master ts-node ./tools/index.ts",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "clean": "gatsby clean"
  },
```